# Writing optional data to Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

With Firebase Swift 2 version, I was able to do:

```
something = ["someOptionalData": optionalData]
ref.updateChildValues(something,......})
```

After converting to Swift 3 & latest Firebase, I've got this error:

```
Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue at optionalData. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.
```

After some googling, people are saying that firebase doesn't accept optional type.

So may I know what is the better way of handling it other than this:

```
if let unwrappedOptionalData = optionalData {
        something = [
            "someOptionalData": unwrappedOptionalData
        ]
} else {
        something = [
            "someOptionalData": true
        ]
}
ref.updateChildValues(something,......)
```

Comment: Your snippet could be reduced to `something = ["someOptionalData": optionalData ?? true]`

Comment: @dan but I don't want to store anything as "someOptionalData" when optionalData is nil, I have tried `something = ["someOptionalData": optionalData ?? NSNull()]` but xcode prompts `Left side of nil coalescing operator ?? has non-optional type Any, so the right side is never used`

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

```
something = ["someOptionalData": optionalData!]
ref.updateChildValues(something,......)
```

Given that your **optionalData** is of type:- *NSNumber*, *NSString*, *NSDictionary* or *NSArray*.

Comment: But that's force unwrapping. In my case, there's actually some other data to be written together with the optional data. What I want to do is, the optional data can be nil, if it is nil then only the non optionals and not nil optionals will be written to firebase. It was possible with Firebase Swift 2.

Comment: @Dravidian is it possible in Swift 3?